# Question about rsnapshot configuration

Tags: rsnapshot

I'm setting up the rsnapshot for backups. I've seen in the configuration file, the following backup lines are not commented by default. Should I leave them uncommented or not ?

I'm not interested in backing up my system, just specific folders.

```
backup  /home/          localhost/
backup  /etc/           localhost/
backup  /usr/local/     localhost/
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's safe to comment them.  they're just examples of common usage on workstations.

Of course, on most servers these directories won't change frequently, so backing them up won't take much time nor space.  I usually keep them (and at least the `/etc` can be handy to check if you break something)

Comment: ok thanks, one more thing if possible.. in the end of the tutorial they suggests to run "/usr/local/bin/rsnapshot hourly" to perform the first backup. Is it just running rsnapshot once ? Or it enables a hourly schedule ?

Comment: @Patrick: just once.  all scheduling is done by `cron`, in line with the "do one thing only" spirit of Unix